# The right way in SQL to deal with a difference between no value and a zero value in an INT datatype field

Tags: sql, mysql, integer

I was having issues with an INT field where there may be no value, a zero value, or an integer above zero and since

```
SELECT foo FROM bar where foo = ''
```

evaluates identically to

```
SELECT foo FROM bar where foo = 0
```

I redefined foo like to  foo INT(11) NULL so that rows where no value for foo is supplied do not get selected by either foo = 0 or foo = '' but only by foo IS NULL

Is this a Good Way to deal with a difference between no value and a zero value?

Comment: Alternatively, [How To Handle Missing Information Without Using NULL](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; nulls are the correct way to specify that a field has no value.